# Why does Takuto break Wako's seal at the end of Star Driver?

Tags: star-driver

The final episode of Star Driver is somewhat confusing to me. While it's clear what events took place, I don't understand why some of the characters did what they did.

Specifically, why does Takuto decide to break Wako's seal to unleash the cybodies into the normal world?

[image]

For the entire series:

- The Glittering Crux Brigade seeks to break the seal of all 4 maidens to achieve the 5th phase.
- Takuto was pretty much fighting against them for the entire series to stop this process.

So why, in the final episode, does he "change his mind" and break Wako's seal?

(Note that is it implied that Wako actually allows Takuto to break her seal.)

Comment: I usually wait a few days to see if a better answer arrives. And only if there are upvotes from other people to verify that it is correct or at least sounds reasonable. But meh, this one has sat around for long enough. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's been long, that's why I commented in the first place. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It was because he wanted to save Sugata**

Sugata wanted to seal Samekh with him forever, meaning he wanted to sacrifice himself. And Takuto wanted to save him, that's why he broke Wako's seal. Takuto's only chance of saving him was to break Wako's seal to unseal the Zero Time. Wako wanted to save Sugata as well that's why she allowed Takuto to break her seal, agreeing both without a single word (which was just amazing for me!).

I hope I answered your question clear. This is purely based on my understanding of the ending. :)